# Check if model field exists in Django

Tags: python, django

This is the solution I came up, in my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

@classmethod
def model_field_exists(cls, field):
    try:
        cls._meta.get_field(field)
        return True
    except models.FieldDoesNotExist:
        return False

models.Model.field_exists = model_field_exists
```

And use it like:

```
Post.field_exists('title') # > True or False
```

The problem comes with foreign keys, my Post model belongs to a Category, this check works:

```
Post.field_exists('category') # > True
```

But this one doesn't:

```
Post.field_exists('category_id') # > False
```

This is the actual field name in db and I need to check for it like this. How can I do it in django?

Comment: Should you check the category model itself in that case?

Comment: What do you mean? I need to check if 'category_id' is a valid field name for the model 'Post'.

Comment: If `category` is a foreign key, and `id` belongs to `category`, then `Post` does not have that field, so why wouldn't you call `Category.field_exists('id')`

Comment: Hey @C.B., I think you misunderstood. Let me explain my case: I have a flat dictionary coming from a webservice. This dict contains data for both models, Post and Category fields, I need to programmatically separate which field belongs to each model. In this case "category_id" field belongs to the "Post" model.

Comment: You should mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 22):

hasattr(cls,field) will not work in all cases, for example where mixins are used.  A safe test is:

```
            try:
                model._meta.get_field(field)
                .. do stuff here
            except FieldDoesNotExist:
                pass
```

or

```
            field = None
            try:
                field = model._meta.get_field(field)
            except FieldDoesNotExist:
                pass

            if field:
              .. do stuff here
```

Comment: This does not solve his problem that category_id isn't found with get_field.

Comment: `name 'FieldDoesNotExist' is not defined`

Comment: `from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist`

Answer (score 18):

You can use getattr to return a default value if the field does not exist.. like below

```
getattr(table, field, False)
```

Comment: in this way you check also properties and methods

Comment: Would just like to add that although this method is very simple and clean, it is not fool-proof in the sense that it does not guard against checking for any non-fields. i.e. it would also return a value for a method name (see the above comment). If your goal is to only check for fields, you should use `isinstance(getattr(table, field, False), django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute)` to make sure you are getting back a field, and nothing else

Comment: in that case I guess you can just use `hasattr(table, field)`

Answer (score 7):

Your 'category_id' field is a *hidden* field in the terminology of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/ . It can't be retrieved by get_field.

Maybe loop over all the fields and check their names; get_fields can return hidden fields:

```
for field in cls._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True):
    if field.name == field:
        return True
return False
```

If you need to care about fields that have their db_column changed from their default, you can test field.db_column too (but it is unset if it wasn't set explicitly).

Answer (score 7):

> But this one doesn't:
>
> Post.field_exists('category_id') # > False
>
> This is the actual field name in db and I need to check for it like this. How can I do it in django?

The case for everything aside from the `_id` part is sufficiently answered in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39388897/1092940). For handling the _id cases, you would basically need a special conditional *in addition to* that answer to appropriately deal with these cases. Something resembling this:

```
if field_name.endswith('_id'):
    try:
        field = model._meta.get_field(field_name.strip('_id'))
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        return False
    if not f.is_relation:
        return False
    return True
```

The additional check is needed to assure that the field minus `_id` returns a ForeignKey, as opposed to some other type of field that just happens to have the same name, which would mean the `name_id` field on the model is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need this? The idea of Object Relational Mappers is for the classes to describe/define the database. So if you want to test the type of a Model you should use `isinstance` like so:

```
if isinstance(model, Post):
    # model is a Post, Post has a publish()
    model.publish()
elif isinstance(model, Comment):
    # model is a Comment, Comment has a foo()
    model.foo()
```

Your model definitions define your schema. There should not be a reason to have to test for the existence of a field. If there is, you might not be following best practice by assigning fields with `setattr`?

Comment: I agree if you are only using features provided by Django out of the box, you should avoid manually setting or accessing things other than the suggested way. However,  there's a need to write more generic logic like for a base class or mixin to keep the code DRY, and hard-coding models in if-else block will end up with a lot of copy-pasting. In such case, dynamically checking if fields exist in a model seems more reasonable to me. Still, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

```
YourModelName.objects.filter(YourModelField=TheFieldToCheck).exists()
```